# Are my solutions correct(integration)?

Tags: calculus, integration

(i)

\begin{align}
\int cos^7 x\,dx& = \int cos^6(x)\,cos (x)dx= \int (1-sin^2 x)^3 \,dx=
\int(1-3sin^2x+3sin^4x-sin^6x)cos(x)dx\,=
\int(cos(x)-3sin^2x\,cos(x)+3sin^4(x)cos(x)-sin^6(x)cos(x))\,dx=
sin x-sin^3x+\frac{3}{5}sin^5x- \frac{1}{7}sin^7(x)+c
\end{align}

(ii)

$\int_{0}^{1} arcsin(x)\, dx=\int_{0 }^{1}1 \cdot arcsin(x)\, dx=$ Let be $u=arc sin(x)$ and $v^{'}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$and $v=x$. So $\int_{0 }^{1} 1 \cdot arcsin(x)\, dx=[x\, arcsin\,x]_{0}^{1}-\int_{0 }^{1} \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx=[x\, arc sin (x)]_{0}^{1}-[-\sqrt{1-x^2}]_{0}^{1}=1\, arc\, sin \,1-0\,arc\, sin0 +\sqrt{1-1^2}-\sqrt{1-0^5} $

(i)In the first solution I can't understand the very last step. $\int(cos(x)-3sin^2x\,cos(x)+3sin^4(x)cos(x)-sin^6(x)cos(x))\,dx=
sin x-sin^3x+\frac{3}{5}sin^5x- \frac{1}{7}sin^7(x)+c$

Comment: What don't you get about the last step?  If you are unsure, you could always differentiate the left side to see if it becomes the integrand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int cos^7(x) dx = 
\int (1-sin^2 (x))^3 d(sin (x))  
$$
Use [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) or [$(a+b)^3$ identity](http://www.web-formulas.com/Math_Formulas/Algebra_Polynomials_Basic.aspx) to expand the integrand and use the [$x^n$ integral](http://math2.org/math/integrals/more/x%5En.htm) formula for the next step to obtain: 
$$
sin x - \frac{3}{3}sin^3 (x) +\frac{3}{5}sin^5 (x) - \frac{1}{7}sin^7 (x) + C$$ $$=
sin x - sin^3 (x) +\frac{3}{5}sin^5 (x) - \frac{1}{7}sin^7 (x) +C$$